# Python file handling / counting amounts in file

Tags: python, file, printing, counting

This code is to read from a file then count the amount of times the same ip comes up and print the results to a file i have made called results.csv, it is printing to the PowerShell on python but not to the file and the counter is not adding up.

```py
infile = open("full_log.txt","r")
iplist = {}  # create an empty dict
item_list = {}

for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()   
    if line: 
        iplist.setdefault(line, 0) # 
        iplist[line] += 1 # increment

for key in iplist.keys():
    line = "%-15s = %s" % (key, iplist[key])
    if key in iplist:
        # the count is not working
        iplist[key] += 1
    else:
        iplist[key] = 1

print(line)   # print uf desired.

item_list = [(k, v) for k, v in infile.items()]

# 2 Sort the list by v
item_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

# it wont print to my file i have made
result_file = open("results.csv", "w")

for counter in range(1):
    current_pair = item_list[counter]
    result_file.write(current_pair[0] + "," + str(current_pair[1]) + "\n")

result_file.close()
```

Comment: Your code is missing indentations. Please fix it.

Comment: this is the only way i could upload it sorry

Comment: You can click the [edit] link to edit it. The indentation is crucial here because it determines how your program works.

Comment: i have it indented properly on my code editor its just when i uploaded in here

Comment: Sure, but fix it here if you want help. If you don't, then you can leave it like it is.

Comment: i have set it up how it is done on my code editor

Comment: i have it printing out but not counting or printing to the file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happens if you indent it wrong like this:

[image]

But if that's the place where your bug is, I'm guessing it's the reason. This is how you indent if-else:

```
for key in iplist.keys():
    line = "%-15s = %s" % (key, iplist[key])
    if  key in iplist:
         iplist[key] += 1
    else:
         iplist[key] = 1
```

Comment: i have sorted this but am i still not get anything printing to my file or counting the number the same IP address comes up is not working

Comment: Debug your code, add printing etc. to see what goes wrong

Comment: i have done that and its not showing any problems